# Avaya CMS - how to get data with php?

Tags: php, avaya

Is it possible to get data from Avaya CMS (16.3) (for call centers) with PHP?
I want to create a real-time statistics with PHP but i don't know how to get data from database :/

Comment: Probably, but you would need to know what type of database it is.

Comment: @SSHThis ok, but how to connect with it? I found in documentation of Avaya that I should use ODBC, is that correct?

Comment: Open database connectivity is certainly supported by PHP: http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/node/view/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is searching for an answer - yes, it is possible but partially.

You need to create a script from the CMS SuperVisor to export data to the TXT file. Next using PHP you need to load this file to the database.
I am using this solution without problems for last 3 years.

Comment: Hi - Just wondering if you are still using the same setup and if you are still having issues? I am also using a similar setup, export to Csv and read file with nodejs. I get VB error 52 at least once a day which halts all the exports (exporting and reading more than one report).

Comment: Hi - no issues in exporting tool. Export tools from avaya is run every 5 seconds without problems. Also thanks to this soultion you do not need free licences as this method uses ssh/ftp connection which is "free" in avaya licence

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What do you mean by Export Tools? Is this an avaya package, or something 3rd Party?

Comment: Avaya, I don't remember exactly how it works because I meanwhile I have changed work but as far as i know you have to create a (custom) report in Avaya CMS Supervisor, next save it as as report .acsup or somehow (there are two kind of them, use this with longer name), and set some cron task to run this report.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC is of no use for real time data since there is no ODBC interface to Real Time Database (RTDB) in CMS. The only practical solution to get that data is to run terminal reports with CLINT, parse them and store that data in your database. See [Tek-Tips thread](http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=397058&page=1) that has some information on how to do this.

Another option is to use [CMS Webdash](http://demo.cmswebdash.com), which a web interface for CMS but can be used as data source too.

Comment: but how to use this CMS Webdash? It's only a demo, and in our web interface for CMS all datas are in adobe flash so it's impossible to get it :(

Comment: CMS Webdash replicates real time CMS data in its own database that can be accessed easily, unlike RTDB in CMS. The demo is there for you to try out web interface; I believe there is an email address on the demo site that you can write to if you have questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like an older Avaya-switch? In that case, the console based client (hopefully included) on the CMS-server - clint - could be used for screen scraping. It's quite a project writing custom reports from scratch and then make another application log on, start clint and begin scraping that report, but it works and may be an alternative if there is no database-access.

I don't know much about newer Avaya-switches, but they may have more features than this..

Answer (score -1):

You can use clintSVR which is a high level tool based on CMS CLINT. By using clintSVR, you can use CGI, OCX and C++ interfaces to get the real time data from CMS. For PHP, you can use CGI interface to get the real time data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.